# How to Set Up a Scene with Large Units of Scale

Tags: objects, scale, units

So recently I've been getting into these "Spaceship" scenes where smaller ships are flying around a much larger ship. And I was wondering there was anything I could do to adjust the units of scale in order to get accurate sizes to the lore of the spaceships. (EX: how to accurately represent the scale of the USS Arizona in Blender)

Answer (score 0):

In my Blender 2.8 default length is in meters, so you can just hit N and write "180m" in scaleX for ship length. And say, "0.5m" for smaller ships.